# Get the current thread id and process id as integers?

Tags: rust

Is there a way to get the current process id and thread id in Rust as integers?

The closest I got was `::std::thread::current().id()` which returns an opaque `ThreadId` object. When trying to access its `u64` field, I'm getting:

```
error[E0611]: field `0` of tuple-struct `std::thread::ThreadId` is private
 --> src\main.rs:4:13
  |
4 |     let x: u64 = ::std::thread::current().id().0;
  |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I couldn't find anything related to the process id in the standard library.

Comment: As of 2023, you can get it In the nightly build by using `thread::current().id().as_u64()`, docs: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/struct.ThreadId.html#method.as_u64

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Thread id

I don't think that `ThreadId` even tracks this. The [implementation of `ThreadId`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.21.0/src/libstd/thread/mod.rs#L875-L899) only has a 64-bit counter that increases with each thread; it does not appear to do anything regarding the underlying threading system.

If you have the [`JoinHandle`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/struct.JoinHandle.html), you can get the ID from the underlying thread system. Once you have that, you can call the appropriate thread system function to get its ID and *potentially* the OS' ID

On Linux, you can get the pthread_t handle via [`JoinHandleExt::as_pthread_t`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/unix/thread/trait.JoinHandleExt.html#tymethod.as_pthread_t). You can likely get an equivalent on other platforms where pthreads is not available.

Note that

> The thread ID returned by `pthread_self()` is not the same thing as the kernel thread ID returned by a call to `gettid(2)`.
>
> [`pthread_self` manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_self)

## Process id

This was stabilized in Rust 1.26 as [`process::id`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/fn.id.html).

Comment: The [docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/struct.ThreadId.html) also make a point of stating that *"`ThreadId`s are not guaranteed to correspond to a thread's system-designated identifier"*.