# How can I get the Linux PID for a thread?

Tags: linux, multithreading, rust, operating-system

I'm interested in obtaining the PID of a thread created inside a Rust program. As stated in the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/struct.Thread.html#method.id), `thread::id()` does not work for this purpose. I found [Get the current thread id and process id as integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47075469/get-the-current-thread-id-and-process-id-as-integers) that seemed like the answer, but my experiments show it doesn't work.

This is the code:

```
extern crate rand;
extern crate libc;

use std::thread::{self, Builder};
use std::process::{self, Command};
use rand::thread_rng;
use rand::RngCore;
use std::time::Duration;
use std::os::unix::thread::JoinHandleExt;
use libc::pthread_t;

fn main() {
    let main_pid = process::id();
    println!("This PID {}", main_pid);

    let b = Builder::new().name(String::from("LongRunningThread")).spawn(move || {
        let mut rng = thread_rng();
        let spawned_pid = process::id();
        println!("Spawned PID {}", spawned_pid);
        loop {
            let u = rng.next_u64() % 1000;
            println!("Processing request {}", u);
            thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(u));
        }

    }).expect("Could not spawn worker thread");

    let p_threadid : pthread_t = b.as_pthread_t();
    println!("Spawned p_threadid {}", p_threadid);
    let thread_id = b.thread().id();
    println!("Spawned thread_id {:?}", thread_id);

    thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(60_000));
}
```

The output from running the program inside a Linux machine is the following:

```
This PID 8597
Spawned p_threadid 139858455706368. <-- Clearly wrong
Spawned thread_id ThreadId(1) <-- Clearly wrong
Spawned PID 8597
Processing request 289
Processing request 476
Processing request 361
Processing request 567
```

The following is an excerpt from the output of htop in my system:

```
 6164  1026 root       20   0   98M  7512  6512 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.03 │  ├─ sshd: dash [priv]
 6195  6164 dash       20   0   98M  4176  3176 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.20 │  │  └─ sshd: dash@pts/11
 6196  6195 dash       20   0 22964  5648  3408 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.09 │  │     └─ -bash
 8597  6196 dash       20   0  2544     4     0 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 │  │        └─ ./process_priorities
 8598  6196 dash       20   0  2544     4     0 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 │  │           └─ LongRunningThre
```

The PID I want from the spawned thread is 8598, but I can't figure out how to obtain it in a Rust program. Any ideas?

Comment: The linked answer shows how to get a pthread ID. I've updated this question and the other answer clearly state that pthread vs OS (specifically Linux) ID (what is reported by htop).

Comment: Shit. So you are telling me the pthread_id is yet another intermediate id that needs to be mapped to the OS PID? Any suggestions on how to get the PID from that?

Comment: I don't know for sure. I'd try [`gettid`](https://docs.rs/nix/0.13.0/nix/unistd/fn.gettid.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer using an existing crate called [Palaver](https://crates.io/crates/palaver). It includes a `gettid()` that works across platforms. The only caveat is that the default configuration of the crate uses nightly features, so if you are on stable, make sure to disable them like this `palaver = { version = "*", default-features = false }`

Now, when I run the code that uses `gettid()`, this is the output:

```
This PID 9009
Priority changed for thread
Spawned PID 9010
Processing request 803
Processing request 279
Processing request 624
```

And the output from my htop:

```
 6164  1026 root       20   0   98M  7512  6512 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.03 │  ├─ sshd: dash [priv]
 6195  6164 dash       20   0   98M  4176  3176 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.21 │  │  └─ sshd: dash@pts/11
 6196  6195 dash       20   0 22964  5648  3408 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.10 │  │     └─ -bash
 9009  6196 dash       20   0  2544     4     0 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 │  │        └─ ./process_priorities
 9010  6196 dash       20   0  2544     4     0 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 │  │           └─ LongRunningThre
```